# How to unit test a Controller method that has a RequestParam of an object?

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I have a controller mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(@RequestParam("id") Person aPerson, Model aModel) {

    aModel.addAttribute("person", aPerson);
    return "index";
}
```

How do I go about testing this through MockMvc?

I can do something like this

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/something?id=1")).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
```

But this will not work since the RequestParam is an object, not a String. The conversion is done by Spring but I'm unit testing the method and do not want to start up the application context. How do I unit test something like this with MockMvc?

Comment: If you had to document your HTTP API so that it can be used by a client, how would you do? What would you say about which parameters can be passed? If you don't know, then that's a problem, because you don't know how the API you created can be used. If you do know, then you have your answer: send the parameters that your API expects: your test is a client of your API. The fact that you use a POJO to gather them is an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm writing missing unit tests for some legacy code, so I didn't write the Controller. I can easily unit test it without the use of MockMvc by simply calling the method and asserting that the String response is the path to the correct view, along with verifying that the model contains an attribute "person". My question is how to do it through MockMvc however, because I made it a habit to write all of the other unit tests using the above mentioned pattern.

Comment: The API expects a single param named "id". Look at the code of Person to knwo what the type of this ID is supposed to be.

Comment: @JohnDoe did you check out my answer? should work.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
       Model model= new Model();
       mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/something?id=1")
         .content(asJsonString(model))
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
```